# In SQL how to validate dynamic key-value pairs against key-value columns

Tags: sql, hana

I have a SQL table that contains key - value pairs, looks like this:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| product_id | iphone_14 |
| product_id | iphone_14_pro |
| country_code | USA |
| country_code | CA |

Those rows identify allowed key-value pairs, meaning if a combination of key and value is not in the table - than it is invalid.

In the API request I would receive dynamic key - value pairs and I need to identify which of them are **invalid**.

For example, when I get these data:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "product_id",
    "value": "iphone_14"
  },
  {
    "key": "product_id",
    "value": "iphone_14_pro"
  },
  {
    "key": "country_code",
    "value": "INVALID_VALUE"
  },
  {
    "key": "country_code",
    "value": "USA"
  }
]
```

we can say that item #3 in array is invalid, since `INVALID_VALUE` is not in the column of allowed values for `country_code`.

How would I write a SQL query that would identify invalid key-value pairs passed. Like in this case, I would have to identify that invalid `key` is `country_code` and invalid `value` is `INVALID_VALUE` (#3 item in the array).

Please note: all of the data is dynamic.

*UPDATE*: I am using SAP HANA dbms, tough I understand there are not so many people using it. So, maybe the answer can provide some general guidelines on how to do it.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? There's a wide variance in support and syntax for json.

Comment: I am using SAP HANA DBMS, though I understand there are not so many people using it. If possible, the answer can be generic.

Comment: Isn't one column missing? (How else can you pair values together?)

Comment: Not sure what you mean @jarlh, which column do you mean?

Comment: How do you know if the iphone_14_pro belongs to USA or CA?

Comment: I don't, the data is not related. The table is just a collection of key-value pairs. @jarlh

Comment: One way would be to pass in the json as a string use the JSON_TABLE to create the table and then use the set operator EXCEPT to subtract those that exist in the valid table.  This would give you a result set of the invalid ones.  Set based operations are generally very effecient on compairisons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more details, it is hard to determine what the most efficient solution in your context would be. But if you are looking for one statement, which does the job based on your JSON input, you could consider using function [JSON_TABLE](https://help.sap.com/docs/hana-cloud-database/sap-hana-cloud-sap-hana-database-sql-reference-guide/json-table-function-json):

```
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE('[
          {"key": "product_id","value": "iphone_14"},
          {"key": "product_id","value": "iphone_14_pro"},
          {"key": "country_code","value": "INVALID_VALUE"},
          {"key": "country_code","value": "USA"}
        ]', '$' 
        COLUMNS 
        (
            KEY nvarchar(20) PATH '$.key', 
            VALUE nvarchar(20) PATH '$.value'
        )
) WHERE (KEY, VALUE) NOT IN (SELECT KEY, VALUE FROM VALIDATION)
```

Comment: thank, works like magic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an executable example:

```
With SrcTable as (SELECT 'product_id' as key, 'iphone_14' as value from dummy union all
SELECT 'product_id' as key, 'iphone_14_pro' as value from dummy union all
SELECT 'country_code' as key, 'USA' as value from dummy union all
SELECT 'country_code' as key, 'CA' as value from dummy)
 
 
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE('[
          {"key": "product_id","value": "iphone_14"},
          {"key": "product_id","value": "iphone_14_pro"},
          {"key": "country_code","value": "INVALID_VALUE"},
          {"key": "country_code","value": "USA"}
        ]', '$' 
        COLUMNS 
        (
            KEY nvarchar(20) PATH '$.key', 
            VALUE nvarchar(20) PATH '$.value'
        ))
EXCEPT --AKA MINUS
SELECT key, value FROM srcTable
```

To make work for you:

- Eliminate the srctable with statement and replace the srcTable with
  your validation table name following the "EXCEPT"
- You'll also need to pass in the string in the JSON_TABLE as a input parameter with a string with the assumption it has the key/value format as an input parameter with the limits defined in COLUMNS of the JSON_TABLE table value function.  However, if the JSON values are stored somehwere already in the hana db; then they could be just selected.  it is unclear how this value is to be made availale to the query.

Set based operators typically perform efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

A simple yet not very performant solution would be to loop over the key-value pairs you receive via the API and then query if the provided pair is in the table with the valid combinations. Like this (pseudocode)

```
for k, v in kvpairsreceived do
  rowsfound = query("SELECT COUNT(0) FROM tablewithvalidcombos WHERE Key = k AND Value = v")
  if rowsfound < 1
    reportInvalidPair(k,v)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I was hoping for something more performant.